# Compute the FFT inverse without using the FFT forward

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fft, emgucv, ifft

I'm trying to compute the FFT inverse without using the FFT forward, but it returns just a black image. I'm using EmguCV in C#. I'm using this code:

```
Matrix<float> reverseDft = new Matrix<float>(m_rows, m_cols, 2);
CvInvoke.cvDFT(data, reverseDft, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_INV_SCALE, 0);
Matrix<float> reverseDftMagnitude = GetDftReal(reverseDft);

pictureBox1.Image = Matrix2Bitmap(reverseDftMagnitude);
```

`data` is my image with 2 channels (real and imaginary).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse Fourier transform of a black image is a black image. You don't write any data to `reverseDft`, so you shouldn't expect any data in the output either.